How to keep device firmware updated when I installed it manually?
My laptop is new enough that the firmware-linux package in debian testing's apt  does not yet contain firmware for it. Hence, I've downloaded the files from linux-firmware.git on kernel.org, copied them to /lib/firmware, and updated the initramfs (more about that process).
That helped for the ethernet, wifi, (and not yet bluetooth ...) but now what?
How can I ensure I will get driver updates, without having to manually check for them?
At some point, the updated drivers will hopefully make it to my distribution. Does it suffice to already apt install packages like firmware-linux  and firmware-realtek? Or will that cause problems once they do provide the same files?

You may never install firmware related packages or updated firmware files and use you computer as long as you want. It's solely up to you.
From a security standpoint it makes sense to install updated CPU microcode but since it's your own device and you're unlikely to provide e.g. shared VPS hosting on it, you may never install updates for it as well.

As for me personally that's how I do it:

I do not install any firmware packages
I identify what's missing and required for my HW to work
I git pull and install only the required firmware files (thus my /lib/firmware is just a few megabytes, vs. two gigabytes installed for you by your distro)
Every month or so I git pull the Linux firmware repo and if firmware files have been updated, I install their new versions (while backing up older versions because sometimes new firmware files result in your HW malfunctioning).

The way the Linux kernel is developed is, IMO, a pure insanity. In Windows, firmware files are part of drivers and you update them together in a single package. There's never a situation when you have new drivers and old firmware files or vice versa. In Linux, the kernel is decoupled from the firmware files and in rare cases kernel drivers (modules) may require a specific version of firmware.

The reason for the "pure insanity" is a legal one. Hardware vendors don't always maintain drivers for Linux, so the community needs to develop their own drivers. But the firmware files are protected by copyright, and packaging them together with GPL'd or other Open Source code would bring legal trouble in some jurisdictions. Even redistributing the firmware files in the linux-firmware Git repo requires a license from the copyright holder, hence the large number of LICENSE.* files in the repository.
